# Cannot properly write a trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I've created a view from a table named Carti and updated some of its contents, and in doing so automatically updating the original contents of the table Carti. To prevent this from happening I tried writing a trigger which sets the new price equal to the old one. I have been unable to make it work. I'm getting the following error:

```
View TOP_3_CARTI created.

>>Query Run In:Query Result 4

Error starting at line : 370 in command -
UPDATE top_3_carti
SET pret = 1.15*pret
Error at Command Line : 370 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04098: trigger 'SAVUA_49.ROLLBACK_PRETURI' is invalid and failed re-validation
04098. 00000 -  "trigger '%s.%s' is invalid and failed re-validation"
*Cause:    A trigger was attempted to be retrieved for execution and was
           found to be invalid.  This also means that compilation/authorization
           failed for the trigger.
*Action:   Options are to resolve the compilation/authorization errors,
           disable the trigger, or drop the trigger.

Trigger ROLLBACK_PRETURI compiled

LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
7/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "SELECT" 
Errors: check compiler log
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW top_3_carti
AS
    SELECT c.* FROM Carti c WHERE c.id_carte IN (
        SELECT c.id_carte
        FROM Carti c, Continut_vanzari cv
        WHERE c.id_carte = cv.id_carte
        GROUP BY c.id_carte, c.pret
        ORDER BY SUM(cv.cantitate) DESC
        FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
    );

SELECT * FROM top_3_carti;

UPDATE top_3_carti
SET pret = 1.15*pret;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rollback_preturi
BEFORE UPDATE ON Carti
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.pret != :OLD.pret THEN
        :NEW.pret := :OLD.pret;
    END IF;
END rollback_preturi;

SELECT c.* FROM Carti c WHERE c.id_carte IN (
        SELECT c.id_carte
        FROM Carti c, Continut_vanzari cv
        WHERE c.id_carte = cv.id_carte
        GROUP BY c.id_carte, c.pret
        ORDER BY SUM(cv.cantitate) DESC
        FETCH FIRST 3 ROWS ONLY
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should terminate PL/SQL scripts with a slash character:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER rollback_preturi
BEFORE UPDATE ON Carti
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.pret != :OLD.pret THEN
        :NEW.pret := :OLD.pret;
    END IF;
END rollback_preturi;
/                                  --> this
```

---

If you executed statement-by-statement (strictly! paying attention to run one at a time), your "original" code would work. But, if you executed it as a script, then Oracle *presumes* that `SELECT` (that follows `CREATE TRIGGER`) also belongs to trigger and that's not valid, so trigger was created with errors.

---

**[EDIT]**

There's no point in allowing change to `pret` value and then rolling it back - simply *prevent* it from happening. How? Use `raise_application_error`; error code can be any value between -20000 and -20999 (these are reserved for us, developers). For example:

```
SQL> create or replace trigger rollback_preturi
  2    before update on carti
  3    for each row
  4  begin
  5    if :new.pret <> :old.pret then
  6       raise_application_error
  7         (-20000,
  8          'You can not update PRET! Old value = ' || :old.pret ||
  9          ', new value = ' || :new.pret);
 10    end if;
 11  end;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL> select * from carti;

  ID_CARTE       PRET
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200

SQL> update carti set pret = 300 where id_carte = 1;
update carti set pret = 300 where id_carte = 1
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: You can not update PRET! Old value = 100, new value = 300
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.ROLLBACK_PRETURI", line 3
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.ROLLBACK_PRETURI'
```

Table contents: nothing has been changed:

```
SQL> select * from carti;

  ID_CARTE       PRET
---------- ----------
         1        100
         2        200
SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. However this brings up a new issue. The trigger now prevents any type of change (which I guess is expected) to the table; is there a way to apply those changed, print the new values out using SELECT and then revert back to the original values?